# Is it possible to restart the Mojolicious Minion worker gracefully?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'd like to be able to gracefully restart the Minion worker I am working on developing (i.e.: without gong back to the command line, killing it and restarting it, which is what I do now).

Is that possible? I'm hoping for something similar to what one can do with a Plack server, i.e.: sending a HUP signal restarts the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [proposed feature](https://github.com/mojolicious/minion/issues/76) - though nobody has worked on it yet.